# 404 page not found on apache server

Tags: apache-2.2, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to get my feet wet with amazon web services and have SSH my instance and created a user, named logan, with admin rights.  I then connected to the EC2 instance with the username and password I had created for the account using Cyberduck and uploaded a plain HTML file to make sure I had things working.

For some reason I cannot connect through my browser to:

```
home/logan/testtestesttest.html
```

I get a 404 page not found error.

I know that Apache was successfully installed though because if I type the elastic IP address in my address bar without any location afterword I get the "It works!" default page.

As far as the security groups for the instance go, I have HTTP open on port 80 to all IP addresses(0.0.0.0/0) and SSH open to my personal IP on port 22.

Thanks in advance,

-Logan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you put the file in `/var/www/html/`?  That's where HTML files go by default.

You can run `apache2ctl -S` to get some output of Apache's configuration and `grep -r DocumentRoot /etc/apache2/` to find out where all the files are served from.

Comment: ok, I grep'd it and it appears that the document root is in /var/www.  I can edit the index.html (what shows up when the elastic ip address is entered) but I can't upload any other files and successfully goto their location with my browser.  any ideas?

Comment: Did you get a "permission denied" error when trying to do the upload?  If so, upload them to your home directory and then do a `sudo mv <filename> /var/www/`.  If it's something else, let us know the error message.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check the apache config file and find out where exactly is the default DocumentRoot. Some distros default is `/var/www/localhost`

Comment: haha why negative vote ? :))